# How to create a diagnoal gradient background in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am looking to create a diagonal gradient background for my webpage. I have been trying to use linear-gradient and adjusting it to fit my clipped shape. I want kind of like a stripe (see picture below). I just want to use vanilla HTML/CSS if possible and I do not want to upload a background image separately.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```css
:root {
  --tan: #f3ebd7;
}

#education {
  background: linear-gradient(
    175deg,
    transparent 0%,
    var(--tan) 25%,
    var(--tan) 75%,
    transparent 100%
  );
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 90px 0;
}

#education .education-header {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#education .education-content {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
#education .education-content h5 {
  font-family: "Fraunces", serif;
}

#education .education-content .education-img {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#education .education-content .education-img img {
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  #education .education-content .education-img {
    padding: 10px 0px;
  }
}

#education .education-content p strong {
  font-family: "Fraunces", serif;
  font-style: normal;
}
#education .education-content p a {
  color: var(--maroon);
}
#education .education-content h6 {
  font-family: "Fraunces", serif;
  letter-spacing: -0.2rem;
}

#education .education-content ul li a {
  color: var(--maroon);
}

#professional-experience {
  background: linear-gradient(10deg, var(--tan) 0%, white 5%);
  padding: 60px 0px;
}

#professional-experience .professional-experience-img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#professional-experience .professional-experience-img img {
  width: 140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#professional-experience .professional-experience-content {
  padding: 20px 48px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 545px) {
  #professional-experience .professional-experience-content {
    padding: 20px 0px;
  }
}
#professional-experience .professional-experience-content h4 {
  font-family: "Fraunces", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#professional-experience .professional-experience-content span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#professional-experience .professional-experience-content p {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<section id="education">
  <section id="education">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="education-header">
          <h1>Education</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="education-content">
            <div class="education-img">
              <img src="images/education-1.webp" alt="" />
            </div>
            <h5>School</h5>
            <span>Program</span>
            <p><strong>GPA:</strong> 4.0/4.0</p>
            <p>
              <a href="#">Description of program
              </p>
              <strong>Honors & Awards:</strong>
              <ul>
                <li>
                 Award
                </li>
                <li>
                 Award
                </li>
                <li>Award</li>
                <li>Honor</li>
                <li>
                  Honor
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="education-content">
              <div class="education-img">
                <img src="images/education-2.webp" alt="" />
              </div>
              <h5>School 2</h5>
              <span
                >Degree <br />
                Minors</span
              >
              <p><strong>GPA:</strong> 3.9/4.0</p>
              <p>
                <strong>Study Abroad:</strong> School
              </p>
              <strong>Honors & Awards:</strong>
              <ul>
                <li>Honor</li>
                <li>Honor</li>
                <li>Award</li>
                <li>Award</li>
                <li>
                 Award
                </li>
                <li>Honor</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
 </section>
 <div id="professional-experience">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="professional-experience-header">
                <h1 class="section-header">Professional Experience</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="professional-experience-img">
              <img src="images/professional-experience-1.webp" alt="" />
              <img src="images/professional-experience-2.webp" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="professional-experience-content">
              <h4>job title</h4>
              <span>company</span>
              <p>Summer 2023 to Present</p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  description
                </li>
                <li>
                  description
                </li>
                <li>
                  Develops a robust, repeatable Natural Language Processing
                  model to parse performance reviews across the organization
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="professional-experience-img">
              <img
                src="images/professional-experience-3.webp"
                alt=""
                class="w-100"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="professional-experience-content">
              <h4>job title</h4>
              <span>company</span>
              <p>Summer 2022</p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  description
                </li>
                <li>
                 description
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

This does not produce the expected result of:
[image: mock up image]

Instead, the lines are still harsh between the two sections (education and professional experience). It is fairly noticeable on larger screen sizes.

Comment: Your anchor tag never closes, you have two elements with the same education id. It's hard to tell from your example what it is you're hoping to accomplish. Are you trying to have the gradient on your clipped element which follows the clip and feathers off to white before it clips?

Comment: When I run your snippet, I see a perfectly smooth diagonal gradient. I don't see any ugly black rectangles, is the snippet supposed to generate those?

Comment: @BrettDonald there's a media query style in there which does not clip the element when the viewport is smaller. If you select full screen you can see the background being clipped due to `clip-path` and `background` being on the same elements.

Comment: Even after viewing the snippet full page, I still do not understand the problem.

Comment: Hi there @BrettDonald the black squares are just a mock up where the text (included) lives. I just care about the background not the front content.

Comment: clip-path polygon is bound to give you straight edges. Have you tried a linear-gradient at an angle instead and what  do you want it to look like on different aspect-ratio viewports?

Comment: i've tried with just linear gradient, but it has a harsh line that i'm not sure how to get rid of. I want it to be more or less the same for different view sizes.

Comment: Updated code for more clarity.